# Why is the rosh chodesh goat not in Rosh Hashana's section of Pin'chas?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf, pinchas

Numbers 28 lists the *musaf* offerings of *rosh chodesh*. They include a goat, which is a *chatas* offering, and several animals as an *ola* offering.

Numbers 29 lists the *musaf* offerings of *Rosh Hashana*. They include just one goat, which is a *chatas* offering. They also include by reference (in verse 6) the *ola* offerings of *rosh chodesh*, since *Rosh Hashana* always coincides with *rosh chodesh*. But they don't mention *rosh chodesh*'s goat. Why not?

(Note that the *rosh chodesh* goat is offered on *Rosh Hashana*, as we see two goats mentioned in the *musaf* prayer. But it's not mentioned in Numbers.)

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117145/170

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is discussed at length by the Rishonim. Ramban says mentioning the olah suffices so we know all the Rosh Chodesh musafim were offered. Chizkuni says the chatat of Rosh Chodesh atones for different types of sin than the chatat of Rosh Hashana so would be inappropriate to mention in the same breath.

But the interesting opinion is that of Rabbeinu Meshulam (a student and contemporary of Rabbeinu Tam) who claims the Torah purposely omitted the chatat of Rosh Chodesh, because the Talmud states that it is brought to atone for Hashem for him making the moon smaller than the sun, and we do not want to mention this on Rosh Hashana. Rabbeinu Tam strongly opposed his opinion and added the mentioning of the chatat in the davening, which as you noted is our custom to this day. See the following sources:

**רמב"ן במדבר פרק כט פסוק ו**:
אבל בראש חודש השביעי, היה במשמע שמה שנאמר (לעיל כח יא) ובראשי חדשיכם תקריבו וגו' יהיה בשאר החדשים כולם, אבל בחדש השביעי יהיה כל קרבנו הקרבן הזה שחדש בו, ועל כן הוצרך לומר מלבד עולת החדש ומנחתה. וכיון שהזכיר כן, כבר למדנו שכל מה שבא בפרשת ובראשי חדשיכם היא מצוה בכל [החדשים] וגם החטאת, ולא הוצרך לומר מלבד עולת החדש ומנחתה וחטאתה:

**תוספות מסכת ראש השנה דף ח עמוד ב**:
והר"ר משולם מפרש שהחדש מתכסה בו שאין חטאת ר"ח קרב בראש השנה כדכתיב מלבד עולת החדש ומנחתה ולא כתיב מלבד חטאת ועולה והקשה לו ר"ת דבריש תוספתא דשבועות תניא (ל') [לב] שעירים מקריבים ישראל בכל שנה וחשיב י"ב בראשי חדשים ובאופן דמוסף דר"ה וחיות אשר הנה מרובעות יסד ר"א הקלירי מוספי חדש עשתי עשרה דהיינו פרים בני בקר שנים ואיל אחד כבשים בני שנה שבעה ושעיר לכפר והשיב לר"ת שלא אמר שאין בו מוסף אלא מתכסה שלא הזכיר הכא חטאת בקרא דמלבד כמו שהזכיר עולה ועוד פי' מתכסה שאין מזכירין מוסף של ר"ח בתפלה משום דאמרי' רשב"ג ה"ל בריה דבסים קליה עייל קמי תיבותא כי מטי לראשי חדשים אישתיק ולא רצה לאמרו פי' דמוטב שיבא זכאי ויכפר על החייב ואל יבא חייב ויכפר על הזכאי פירוש ההוא דר"ח קרוי חייב משום דאמרי' אמר הקב"ה הביאו כפרה וכו' עכ"ל ור"ת רגיל להזכיר ולומר מלבד עולת החדש ולסיים ושני שעירים לכפר חד דר"ח וחד דר"ה.

Rav Meshulam's opinion is also quoted in Sefer Hayashar:

**ספר הישר (חלק התשובות) סימן מג**:
ומה ששמע רבינו אומרים משמי ששעיר ר"ח דאינו קרב, שמע השומע וטעה, כי לא אמרתי שלא היה קרב אלא כך אמרתי שלא היה נזכר במקום שהיה לו להזכר. אלא כסהו התורה ואיזה זה ראש השנה, כי בחומש הפקודים כשהזכיר במוסף ראש השנה ושעיר עזים אחד לחטאת, אמר הכתוב מלבד עולת החודש. הרי דהוא עיקר קרבן החדש ועוד דהא בחטאת משתעי קרא, והיה לו לומר זה חטאת תקריבו מלבד חטאת החודש שכבר קרב, כדרך שהזכיר במוסף של יום הכפורים ושעיר עזים אחד לחטאת מלבד חטאת הכפורים. ולא רצה הכתוב לזכרו וכסהו שלא רצה להזכירו על שבא חטאת לה' על קיטרוג הלבנה ובהבלעה היה קרב.

**חזקוני במדבר פרק כט פסוק ו**:
וא"ת אמאי לא אמר ומלבד חטאת החודש אלא י"ל כל העולות כפרתן שוה עשה ועל לא תעשה הניתק לעשה, ולכך הזכירם זו על זו אבל חטאת ר"ח וחטאת ר"ה אין כפרתן שוה. כיצד של ר"ח מכפר על שאין בו ידיעה לא בתחלה ולא בסוף כמו שפירשו רז"ל מדכתיב ביה לה' אבל של ר"ה מכפר על שאין בה ידיעה בתחילה ויש בה ידיעה בסוף ולכך לא הזכירם זו על זו.

Comment: and there's even a nafka minah lehalacha nowadays regarding the proper text of the musaf for rosh hashana